# Recursion formatting php node->child->child level

Tags: php, recursion, hierarchy

After a day of trying to solve this problem, I have to admit defeat.

Need to format a hierarchy it into a report/csv, where it is indented/hierarchy properly, I need a php function that takes the array, and creates the hierarchy as below. I know that the start node is "Sales";

```
//[so]  [activity]  [milestone] [compleated]
    array(
        array("Sales", "Motor", "Documentation", "10%"),
        array("Sales", "Motor", "Communication", "15%"),
        array("Sales", "Motor", "Metro file", "30%"),
        array("Sales", "Motor", "Training", "33%"),
        array("Sales", "Motor", "Client Services", "23%"),
        array("Motor", "Documentation", "Doc revamp", "42%"),
        array("Motor", "Documentation", "SLA", "33%"),
        array("Motor", "Documentation", "KRA", "25%")
    )

Sales           
    Motor       
        Documentation           10%
            Doc revamp          43%
            SLA                 33%
            KRA                 25%
        Communication           15%
        Metro file              30%
        Training                33%
        Client Services         23%

Sales           
xx Motor        
xxx Documentation           10%
xxxx Doc revamp         43%
xxxxx SLA                   33%
xxxxx KRA                   25%
xxxx Communication          15%
xxxx Metro file             30%
xxxx Training               33%
xxxx Client Services        23%
```

Comment: How do you "indent" in a csv format?

Comment: with " " instead of the x, or was thinking using empty columns "","L2" -> "","","L3"

Comment: It is insane to use csv for this. Take a look at YAML instead: http://www.yaml.org/start.html

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array (it already appears to be sorted).

Initialize $last_so  $last_activity  $last_milestone to null;

loop over all entries in the array.

Extract $so,  $activity,  $milestone;

When $so changes (detected by comparing it to $last_so) output $so as first header, and reset $last_activity  $last_milestone to null;

When $activity changes output $activity as second header, and reset $last_milestone to null;;

When $milestone changes output $milestone as third header

Output the percentage in the fourth column.

Now update $last_so, .. etc to $So, .. etc.

continue loop.